# Limit of cdf of binomial distribution

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers, binomial-distribution

I would like to compute the limit of CDF for a Binomial distribution as $n \rightarrow \infty$, 
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} F( \theta;n,q) = 
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \theta n \rfloor} \binom{n}{k} q^k (1-q)^{n-k} 
\end{equation*}

An hint for this problem can be obtained in this link :
[The asymptotic behavior of the CDF of Binomial distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/861152/the-asymptotic-behavior-of-the-cdf-of-binomial-distribution) 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}F(\theta;n,q) = \begin{cases}0 & \text{if } \theta < q\\1 & \text{if } \theta > q\end{cases}.
$$
My question 1 is : Where and how to apply the Weak Law of Large Number to obtain the solution?

Further more, let 
$$G_n(\theta) = 
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \theta n \rfloor} \binom{n}{k} \int_0^1 q^k (1-q)^{n-k} d W(q). $$

My Question 2 is how to prove that,
$$ G_{\infty}(\theta)  = W(\theta) \text{ in distribution.}$$

Comment: weak law is aabout convergence in probability. strong law is about convergence almost surely. does convergence as imply convergence in distribution? Might this be helpful? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%E2%80%93Laplace_theorem

Comment: @BCLC: thanks for your hints. I got that binomial can be approximated by normal. I have no idea how to apply LLN here to evaluate the sum. From my impression, LLN said that the average of a series iid r.v converges to their expect value. But, where to use it here?

Comment: which sum? dunno about the second question hehehehe. why don't you just ask another question?

Comment: I mean the $\sum_k P(Y=k)$, and how to use LLN to obtain its limit as n goes to infinity

Comment: i guess you mean the weak LLN. Well cdf if $P(X \le x)$ but [weak LLN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Weak_law) has $P(X > x)$. How about $1 - P(X \le x)$?